# Creating Feature Shape Templates in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, digitizing, template

Working in oil & gas, I find myself drawing the same polyline shapes over and over again in my company's pipeline database.

For example, a 12" valve set might always have the same dimensions, a 24" pig launcher might have a couple different designs, a 12" drip might have a couple different designs, and so on.

Most of these items require multiple separate polyline features each with its own attributes (such as a 12" mainline pipe and a 4" bypass pipe) and also the possibility of having multiple separate valve and fitting features that would be snapped to the polylines.

Here is an example of a Pig Launcher which I would like to be able to replicate multiple times in the future without having to draw each individual item every single time.  As you could imagine, this process is time consuming, but it is critical to properly locating unique valves and other appurtenances.

[image: Pig Trap Layout Example]

Here is an example of a fairly simple bypass valve set that would also be a good candidate for replication.

[image: Bypass Layout Example]

Is there a way to have pre-made shape templates that I can just select my template, and rotate and snap into place?

Comment: [As-Built Editing and Analysis](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/gas/help/as-built-editing/) + [Attribute Assistant](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/) gives some of this capability.

Comment: This functionality is available in ArcGIS Pro 1.3 as [Preset Templates](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/create-a-preset-template.htm) and will be enhanced in further releases. It will not be ported to ArcMap.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that As-Built Editing and Analysis is not supported in ArcMap 10.2.2.  I will definitely explore some of the options with ArcGIS Pro if we can ever get it working in our Citrix environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented by @SeanJones](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218557/creating-feature-shape-templates-in-arcmap#comment335582_218557):

> This functionality is available in ArcGIS Pro 1.3 as [Preset
>   Templates](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/create-a-preset-template.htm)
>   and will be enhanced in further releases. It will not be ported to
>   ArcMap.